# Compute an ROC for a hybrid model where only one of the model components computes class probabilities

Tags: random-forest, confusion-matrix

I've created a hybrid model by taking an existing decision engine (`TRUE`/`FALSE` output) and supplementing it with a random forest classifier (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) model. The output of the hybrid model is produced by computing an `OR` from the predictions of the two models.

When evaluating the performance on historical data, I can produce a ROC for the random forest by computing the class probabilities based on the votes from all of the random trees combined. I cannot do this for the existing decision engine because it does not output probabilities. For the purpose of this analysis, I need to treat it as a black box.

**How can I compute an ROC for the hybrid model?** I would like to do this with `R`. I'm imagining that for each point on the ROC of the first model, I would need to compute the lift generated by adding the existing decision engine model.

Comment: I'm thinking that I can define the class probability of the hybrid model as 1 if the existing decision engine outputs `TRUE`, and equal to the random forest class probability if the existing decision engine outputs `FALSE`. Then I should see a lift in the ROC of the hybrid model as I've observed in the confusion matrix for the hybrid model compared to either model alone.